# How to hydrate a spring data neo4j entity with a field that is defined as a List of interaces?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

If my Entity has a field which is a Collection of interface types how can I tell spring data to hydrate each item in the collection based on the correct concrete type? Is there some way I can make a custom mapping which makes spring instantiate a Song class for example if there is some data returned from neo4j that uniquely identifies the record as a Song class (the Song class implements MusicItem)? My musicItems collection below should have multiple entries all with concrete types of MusicItem.

Entity

```
public class Dater implements CSVFormat{

    @Id
    private String userId;

    @Relationship(type = "LISTENS_TO")
    private Set<MusicItem> musicItems = new HashSet<>();
```

MusicItem interface of music that Dater has listened to

```
public interface MusicItem{

    String getName();
    MusicItemType getType();

}
```

Example implementation of MusicItem I want to instantiate when it is returned from db

```
public class Song implements MusicItem{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

}
```

Repository query

```
public interface DaterRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Dater,String>{

    @Query("MATCH (user:Dater { userId: $userId })-[:LISTENS_TO]->(musicItems)<-[mr:LISTENS_TO]-(matches:Dater) "
            + "where id(user) <> id(matches) "
            + "RETURN matches, collect(mr), collect(musicItems) ")
    List<Dater> getMatches(String userId);
```

Example data in db

```
{
  "identity": 2912,
  "labels": [
    "MusicItem",
    "Song"
  ],
  "properties": {
"name": "Youth",
"isrc": "QM6P41904468",
"smallImageUrl": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music123/v4/3e/29/f8/3e29f87e-239e-d85d-f30e-b93689e863ec/194491036614.jpg/75x75bb.jpg",
"mediumImageUrl": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music123/v4/3e/29/f8/3e29f87e-239e-d85d-f30e-b93689e863ec/194491036614.jpg/320x320bb.jpg",
"largeImageUrl": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music123/v4/3e/29/f8/3e29f87e-239e-d85d-f30e-b93689e863ec/194491036614.jpg/640x640bb.jpg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I did something similar with the Java version data where we have child deltas of different types. A colleague showed me how to create an abstract Delta class that several other classes extended. The overridden toString method should give you the type of the subclass coming back. https://github.com/JMHReif/sdn-jdk-versions/blob/gerrits-playground/src/main/java/com/jmhreif/sdnjdkversions/domain/Delta.java